# How to put a curly arrow beside a matrix

Tags: matrices, arrows

I did the following codes:

‎

```
   \documentclass[tikz‎, ‎border=3mm]{standalone}‎  
    \usepackage{easybmat}‎  
‎    \begin{document}‎‎    
‎    \[‎‎‎‎‎‎  
    \begin{array}{}  
    ~\\  
‎    ~\\  
    ~\\  
‎    ~\\  
‎    ~  
    ~‎\\  
‎    ~\\‎  
‎    $k‎‎$\\  
‎    ~‎   
    \end{array}‎
‎    \hspace*{-0.54cm}‎
    \begin{array}{}
    ~\\
‎    ~\\
‎    ~\\
‎    ~\\
‎    ~
‎    $‎‎i‎‎$‎\\
    ~\\
‎    ~‎
    \end{array}‎
‎    \begin{array}{}
    \hspace*{1.5cm}‎\stackrel{j}{\downarrow}\\‎
‎    \left(
‎    \begin{BMAT}{cccccc}{ccccc}
    *‎ & *‎‎ & *‎ & \cdots‎‎‎‎ & * & *‎ ‎‎‎‎‎\\
    0‎‎ & *‎‎ & *‎ & ‎\cdots‎‎ & * & ‎\vdots‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎\\‎‎
‎    \vdots‎ & 0‎‎ & 0‎ & a_{ij}‎‎ & \cdots &‎*‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\\‎‎
    0‎ & \cdots‎‎ & \fbox{‎$‎a_{kj}‎$‎}‎ & a_{k,j+1}‎‎ & \cdots & *‎‎‎‎‎‎\\‎‎
    0‎ & \cdots‎‎ & *& *‎‎ & \cdots & *‎ ‎‎‎‎‎
    \addpath‎{(2,5,1)ddddd}
    \addpath{(3,5,1)ddddd}‎
    \addpath{(0,1,1)rrrrrr}‎
    \addpath{(0,2,1)rrrrrr}‎
    \addpath{(0,3,1)rrrrrr}
‎    \end{BMAT}
‎    \right)‎‎‎‎‎
    \end{array}‎
‎    \hspace*{-0.1cm}‎
‎‎‎‎    \begin{array}{}
    ~\\
‎    ~\\
    ~\\
‎    ~\\
‎    ~‎\\
‎    ~\\
‎    ~‎\\
‎    ~‎‎
‎‎    $\leftarrow ‎k+1‎$‎
    \end{array}‎‎‎
‎‎    \]‎
    \end{document}‎
```

to have the certain matrix as below:

[image]

What could I do if an curly arrow is needed? I mean like this:

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: sorry, where is curly braces? instead of arrow an the second image?

Comment: @Zarko: I misused the word. I meant that vertical arc. Sorry.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i do not understand what this upright arch is. where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that the [easybmat](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) package provides an easy way to draw matrices like this. I don't know this package and instead recommend a `matrix of math nodes` using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). Using this gives something close to what you want:

[image]

The basic idea is that you put things into a "normal" latex matrix, with columns separated by `&`, and then you  draw on the matrix using "normal" [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). The nodes of the matrix are referred to  `(M-<row>-<col>)`, where `row` and `col` are the row and column indices. (The `M` is specified by the `\matrix (M) [...]{...}` in the code below -- if you want to use, for example, `mat` instead of `M` change `(M)` to `(mat)`.) There are some complications to put your internal lines etc into place. Much of this is self-explanatory, but not everything, The box around the `a_{kj}` was the trickiest bit and I added some style to the delimiters as I thought that they were too big and too far away from the matrix. For more details see section 57 of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual. In the OP I was not sure if the the height of the third row should be higher than the other rows. If this is required then you can add something like

```
row 3/.style={minimum height=3em}
```

to the matrix style specifications: `\matrix (M)[...style...]{...}`.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mline/.style={thin,gray},
   boxed/.style={rectangle,minimum width=6mm,draw, text depth=0.5mm,
                 inner sep=0.7mm, text height=1ex},
                 every left delimiter/.style={xshift=.7em,scale=0.9},
                 every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-.7em,scale=0.9},
  ]
  \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,
              left delimiter=(,
              right delimiter=),
              row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
              column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
              nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2.2em,
                     text height=1.8ex, text depth=0},
  ]{ * & * & * & \cdots & * & * \\
       0 & * & * & \cdots & * &\vdots\\
       \vdots & 0 & 0 & a_{ij} & \cdots & * \\
       0 & \cdots & |[boxed]|a_{kj} & a_{k,j+1} & \cdots & *\\
       0 & \cdots & * & * & \cdots & *\\
   };
   \draw[<-] ($(M-5-6)+(0.6,0)$) --++(0.4,0)node[right]{$k+1$};
   \draw[<-] ($(M-1-3)+(0,0.2)$) --++(0,0.4)node[above]{$j$};
   \draw[<->] ($(M-3-1)+(-0.9,0)$)node[right]{$i$} to[out=210, in=150]
                  ($(M-4-1)+(-0.9,0)$)node[right]{$k$};
   \draw[mline](M-1-2.north east) -- (M-5-2.south east);
   \draw[mline](M-1-3.north east) -- (M-5-3.south east);
   \draw[mline](M-2-1.south west) -- (M-2-6.south east);
   \draw[mline](M-3-1.south west) -- (M-3-6.south east);
   \draw[mline](M-4-1.south west) -- (M-4-6.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: op asks about twisted brackets. i admire that you understand from the question that the problem is how to write a matrix. :-). good answer (+1).

Comment: @Zarko: I need to make that double curved arrow near the $I$ and $k$ just to say this rows can be interchanged. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the time. Your solution makes mine fade. +1

Comment: @BabakS., than your problem is solved. you can accept this answer :-)

Comment: The boxed entry is really awful.

Comment: @egreg I don't disagree but it seems to be what the OP wanted....if it really needs to be highlighted then shading would be probably be better.